# Remove the comma from the last object of json object

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I have created a template using jinja2 Which generates the output as expected.

However, I'm trying to remove the comma from the last object of the generated JSON.
I tried using  `{% if loop.last %}`  to get rid of the comma for the last object.

But, I couldn't get the correct output.

```
{% if loop.last %}
    {
    "met" : {{j}},
    "uri" : "{{i}}"
     }
{% endif %}
```

Below is the code and output

```
from jinja2 import Template

uri = ["example1.com","example2.com"]
metric_value = [1024, 2048]

template = Template('''\
[
{%- for i in uri -%}
    {%- for j in met %}
    {
        "met" : {{j}},
        "uri" : "{{i}}"
    },
    {%- endfor -%}
{%- endfor %}
]
''')

payload = template.render(uri=uri, met=metric_value)                                 
print(payload)
```

output:

```js
[
    {
        "met" : 1024,
        "uri" : "example1.com"
    },
    {
        "met" : 2048,
        "uri" : "example1.com"
    },
    {
        "met" : 1024,
        "uri" : "example2.com"
    },
    {
        "met" : 2048,
        "uri" : "example2.com"
    },
]
```

Comment: Are you trying to make JSON with a Jinja template? Why not `json.dumps`?

Comment: I want to do it with jinja tempate

Comment: Yeah, but why though

Comment: @Ry-: there are good reasons to generate the JSON format in the Jinja2 template, provided you use the dedicated `tojson` filter. That value will be HTML escaped too (safe to embed everywhere except in double-quoted HTML attributes, see the documentation I link to in my answer).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: This doesn’t look like JSON in HTML, considering we can see the entire `Template` here. Maybe it is, hence the question of “why”

Comment: @Ry-: I do not expect that this is being used to produce a `application/json` response. They provided a proper MCVE, it is almost certainly a sample abstracted from a larger project. I think we can assume here that there will be more to template.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I disagree that this is likely enough to be a proper MCVE that asking isn’t necessary. (Actually, it flat-out isn’t a proper MCVE, because there’s no indication of where the JSON is used. That’s no problem, though! In such situations, we can *ask for clarification*.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Don't manually generate JSON with Jinja2**. You can't hope to generate save and valid JSON in all circumstances.

When embedding JSON in a larger template, use the [`tojson` built-in filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#tojson) to generate JSON. It will not include a trailing comma.

I'd pass in ready-made dictionaries with the product of the two lists:

```
uri_per_metric = [{'met': m, 'uri': u} for u in uri for m in metric_value]
```

and in the template just use

```
{{ uri_per_metric|tojson(indent=4) }}
```

Demo:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> uri = ["example1.com", "example2.com"]
>>> metric_value = [1024, 2048]
>>> uri_per_metric = [{'met': m, 'uri': u} for u in uri for m in metric_value]
>>> template = Template('''\
... <script type="text/javascript">
... data = {{ uri_per_metric|tojson(indent=4) }};
... </script>
... ''')
>>> payload = template.render(uri_per_metric=uri_per_metric)
>>> print(payload)
<script type="text/javascript">
data = [
    {
        "met": 1024,
        "uri": "example1.com"
    },
    {
        "met": 2048,
        "uri": "example1.com"
    },
    {
        "met": 1024,
        "uri": "example2.com"
    },
    {
        "met": 2048,
        "uri": "example2.com"
    }
];
</script>
```

Of course, if you are producing a `application/json` response (returning *only* JSON data from a web endpoint) and this is not part of a larger template, then using templating *at all* would be a bad idea. In that case use the dedicated JSON support your web framework might have, such as [Flask's `jsonify()` response factory method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#module-flask.json), or produce the output with `json.dumps()` directly.